# File '@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server' not found. Error on installing strapi in linux

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, nuxt-strapi

tsconfig.json:2:14 - error TS6053: File '@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server' not found.

2   "extends": "@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server",
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error(s).

When I tried to install Strapi using npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project command, I got the below error

*Error while installing dependencies:
Keep trying!
Oh, it seems that you encountered errors while installing dependencies in your project.
Don't give up, your project was created correctly.
Fix the issues mentioned in the installation errors and try to run the following command*

But there was no error logs and when I tried yarn install && yarn develop, getting the typescript error.
The node version in my system is v18.4

I have installed Strapi version 4 earlier and it was successful but currently while trying to install using the same command getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `pnpm` try to install the package manually like this:

`pnpm add @strapi/typescript-utils`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `npm` and I still got the issue. I solve this part by installing this package:

```js
npm i @strapi/typescript-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was upgrading strapi, specifically `@strapi/typescript-utils@4.14.4` to `4.15.4`

My fix was updating `tsconfig.json`

- changed
  `"extends": "@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server",`
- to
  `"extends": "./node_modules/@strapi/typescript-utils/tsconfigs/server",`

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have the same issue, to fix use npm install instead of yarn install

```
node v18.7.0
yarn v3.6.1
strapi v4.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Yarn 2+ the default `nodeLinker: pnp` is applied to your local module setting so you can change the config to `nodeLinker: node_modules` inside `.yarnrc.yml` that you should create inside your project directory if not exists. and after that, you should run `yarn install` again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because yarn is trying to use pnp, you can "resolve" the issue by setting it to use the legacy node modules version like by adding the following to the root of your `package.json`

```
"packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"
```

More info available in the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/corepack.html#configuring-a-package).